# Problems while trying to remove a set of tuples from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tuples

Just a quick question guys, I have a long list of tuples like this:

```
a_lis = [('[', '1O--'), ("'", '1B--'),('hi', 'SDFD29384'), ('there','2398SDFDSF'),("'", '1B--'), (']', '1C--')]
```

How can I remove all this tuples (*): `('[', '1O--'), ("'", '1B--'),("'", '1B--'), (']', '1C--')` from `a_lis`?

I tried to:

```
flat_list = filter(flat_list, lambda x: x[0] == '[' && x[1] == "'")
```

However, I got a non iterable error, which is a better way of removing such tuples (*) from my list, in order to get?:

```
a_lis = [('hi', 'SDFD29384'), ('there','2398SDFDSF')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the order of arguments you have give to filter is incorrect.

Just use

```
flat_list = filter(lambda x: x[0] != '[' and x[0] != "'", a_lis)
```

Note: Looking at your data, a better way looks like this:

```
flat_list = filter(lambda x: '--' not in x[1], a_lis)
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comment below, the above code makes flat_list a generator. To get concrete lists, just use list comprehensions:

```
def should_remove(s):
    return '[' in s or ']' in s or "'" in s

flat_list = [x in a_lis if not should_remove(x[1])]
```

OR

```
flat_list = [x in a_lis if '--' not in x[1]]
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way of doing this?... I mean, just remove them all at once?.. also this produced me a generator...

Comment: You need to have a concrete way of deciding what you want to remove. Just change the `should_remove` function in the above example according to whatever rule you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
>>> a_list = [('[', '1O--'), ("'", '1B--'),('hi', 'SDFD29384'), ('there','2398SDFDSF'),("'", '1B--'), (']', '1C--')]
>>> b_list = [('[', '1O--'), ("'", '1B--'),("'", '1B--'), (']', '1C--')]
>>> list(set(a_list) - set(b_list))
[('hi', 'SDFD29384'), ('there', '2398SDFDSF')]
```

Another way would be:

```
>>> [ x for x in a_list if x not in b_list ]
[('hi', 'SDFD29384'), ('there', '2398SDFDSF')]
```

Another couple possibilities:

```
>>> for x in b_list:
        try:
            a_list.remove(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

That one actually modifies `a_list`, so may not be desirable depending on context. There's an analogous method involving `set.remove()` or even `set.discard()` (which wouldn't require the `try` block).

Note that any `set` based methods require all objects in the lists to be hashable - in the example given, they're all tuples, so this is fine. Another caveat in the `set` methods is that the surviving items in the result may not be in the same order they were in the original. Using an `OrderedSet` would work around that, but involves a bit more overhead, as that's not a core package/datatype.

Comment: In terms of complexity which is faster?... the filter or the comprehension list?

Comment: Without testing, I'd have to guess they're going to be fairly similar, at least in the proffered example. The set version might edge out some performance in significantly larger cases, because it'll depend more on comparing hashes than the actual tuples, I think. However, the set version won't work if something in either one of the lists turns out to not be hashable... Also there're other possibilities - e.g. using `list.remove()` would be another method...